# PyroCMS - Pagination won't display on blog module

Tags: pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I'm having some serious trouble getting the pagination to show up on the standard blog module. It's is included as {{ pagination }} with all the included themes, however it seems that count is set to 25 on the back end, and whenever I add a limit="4" for example, the posts are limited, however the pagination still does not show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well it appears it was quite the oversight and I didn't realize that the limit was set on the backend via the "feed item count" dropdown. However, the smallest is still 10 and I would like my blog posts to start paginating at say, 4 or 5, would anyone know how to decrease the feed item count in the backend? One would think it should be a text box option and not a drop down selection...

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the pagination steps outlined on this page ...

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/streams/entry-looping#pagination

Comment: That seems to be for the streams module, I'm trying to paginate the standard blog module which seems to have a bit different syntax.

Comment: blog module runs off streams so should be the same from what I have read on there